# TimeSeries Forecasting in Java

Tags: time-series, weka, forecasting

I'm trying to run TimeseriesExample code for forecasting(predicting) future 6-months data by giving 2-months data in Java. I need to use `WekaForecaster` object. But I'm unable to import these two files:

```
import weka.classifiers.timeseries.WekaForecaster; 
import weka.classifiers.timeseries.core.TSLagMaker;
```

Both of these showing error. I have imported following jar files:

```
weka.jar,
pdm-timeseriesforecasting-ce-TRUNK-SNAPSHOT.jar,
jcommon-1.0.14.jar ,
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
```

But still above files not importing, which jar I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install first the timeseriesForecasting package before use it in your code.

The package(jar file) can be found in wekafiles folder in your user folder.

You must to use the Package Manager to do it.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Use the "package manager" (weka >=3.7) and install the timeSeries plugin. then add the weka-37.jar to your build path. Here some information about the plugin.

[Weka TimeSeries plugin](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka)

By the way, I think that 2 month data is not enough to forecast 6 months.